# How to escape double-quote in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I don't succeed in escaping a double-quote (") in jQuery.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.red { border-top: 10px solid red; }
.yellow { border-top: 10px solid yellow; }
.left { border-left: 3px solid green; } 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="choose">
    <li>Goofy</li>
  <li><a href="blabla.aspx">Mickey</a></li>
  <li><a href="other.ext">Mickey</a></li>
  <li>Pluto</li>
</ul>
    
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p:contains(is)").css("background-color", "yellow");
  $("li:contains('Mickey')").addClass('left');
  $("li:contains('aspx">Mickey')").addClass('yellow');
  $("li:contains('Pluto')").addClass('left');
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't do `aspx">Mickey'` What if the link becomes `<a href="blabla.aspx?foo=bar">Mickey</a>` ? Or even `<a href="blabla.aspx" >Mickey</a>` (notice the space)

Comment: because the hyperlink is actually added by my CMS ... I have no power on it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really a good idea to try to find a piece of literal HTML code with `contains`. HTML tends to change, and even a single space could break the code.

Instead, use [`:has`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and pass a proper selector for the child:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p:contains(is)").css("background-color", "yellow");
  $("li:contains('Mickey')").addClass('left');
  $("li:has(a[href$=aspx]:contains('Mickey'))").addClass("yellow");
  $("li:contains('Pluto')").addClass('left');
});
```

```css
.red { border-top: 10px solid red; }
.yellow { border-top: 10px solid yellow; }
.left { border-left: 3px solid green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="choose">
  <li>Goofy</li>
  <li><a href="blabla.aspx">Mickey</a></li>
  <li><a href="other.ext">Mickey</a></li>
  <li>Pluto</li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, you can also use just the selector of the link itself and get the `li` with [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/).